# Home Improvement link getting 'wrapped' on StackExchange footers

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, hyperlinks, footer

The link to the 'home improvement' site in footer of ALL StackExchange sites is getting line wrapped after 'home' so it looks like a 'home' link instead of a 'home improvement' link.

Add some no-wrap to that baby please!

Edit 1:  Or as Adam pointed out, use `&nbsp;`

[image: StackExchange footer]

Comment: use nonbreaking space &nbsp;

Comment: this already exists on meta.diy AFAIK. Doesn't belong here..

Comment: @jeff.  This is a problem on **ALL StackExchange sites**, not just HomeImprovements.  That's why I posted it here as meta.stackoverflow seems to be place to post non-site-specific StackExchange issues/bugs.

Comment: @david I disagree; it's a UI element that is specific to and comes from that site, and should be handled there.

Comment: @jeff - I'm fine for you to migrate this to wherever you think it should be.  However I still think you are misunderstanding my point.  The screen shot above is NOT from the HomeImprovement SE site, it was taken on the WebApps SE site.  Therefore, it's not a UI element specific to the HomeImprovement SE site (or the WebApps SE site for that matter).  Forgive me if I am wrong, but I'm assuming that the footer content on all SE sites comes from a common template/masterpage/view.  So wouldn't that make the UI element specific to the common template, not the individual sites?  (continued...)

Comment: @jeff - Again, I don't care where this question ends up, I'm more concerned about being a dumbass and getting suckered into clicking the 'home' button again ; )