# Use non-breaking spaces in the footer site list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, footer

I recommend some non-breaking spaces in the footer list of network sites. In the screenshot below, "home improvement" and "area 51" are awkwardly broken up over two lines. Replacing spaces with &nbsp; inside site names would prevent this.

[image]

Comment: +1, but for future reference, freehand circles are typically required to demonstrate this kind of thing. We'll let this one slide :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Home Improvement link getting 'wrapped' on StackExchange footers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59296/home-improvement-link-getting-wrapped-on-stackexchange-footers)

Comment: @Jon, freehand-circled</strong-bad>!  Now you need to find a way to give another upvote.  @Adam, oddly, nbsps were suggested on the dupe by someone else named Adam....

Comment: @Pop - I'll just log on using my [sock puppet account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) and upvote from there.

Comment: @Jon, wouldn't that be breaking character, all things considered?

Comment: Or you could use CSS property `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 3):

The next build will   all the spaces for launched sites.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this has regressed in the web apps footer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been addressed for the Beta sites, but not for all footer links in the graduated sites.

i.e. a sample of the HTML from the beta site template:

```
 <span style="color:#326AB3;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://fitness.stackexchange.com">physical&nbsp;fitness</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <span style="color:#326AB3;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://mechanics.stackexchange.com">motor&nbsp;vehicle&nbsp;maintenance&nbsp;and&nbsp;repair</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

However the graduated sites (for example looking at the HTML on https://stats.stackexchange.com/) shows that *most* of the sites with spaces don't have non-breaking spaces in the text (with the exception of the Home Improvement link, which does).

```
                    <span style="color:#73abb3;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://scifi.stackexchange.com">scifi &amp; fantasy</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#23629F;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://ux.stackexchange.com">user experience</a>&nbsp;
                    <span style="color:#faff72;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://skeptics.stackexchange.com">skeptics</a>&nbsp;.
```

Being the sad man I am, I trawled all the graduated sites to see if it's an issue elsewhere, and found the following:

For instance the link for 'SciFi & Fantasy' is wrapping in the footer of:

- https://cooking.stackexchange.com/,
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/
- http://stats.stackexchange.com
- https://english.stackexchange.com/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/
- https://diy.stackexchange.com/
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Also on https://android.stackexchange.com/ the 'user experience' link wraps too.